# Finding the top values in data frame using r

Tags: r

How can I find the 5 highest values of a column in a data frame

I tried the `order()` function but it gives me only the indices of the rows, wherease I need the actual data from the column.  Here's what I have so far:

```
tail(order(DF$column, decreasing=TRUE),5)
```

Comment: sure you want to use `head(..., 5)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass the result of `order` back to `DF`:

```
DF <- data.frame( column = 1:10,
                  names = letters[1:10])

order(DF$column)
# 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10

head(DF[order(DF$column),],5)
#       column names
# 1      1     a
# 2      2     b
# 3      3     c
# 4      4     d
# 5      5     e
```

You're correct that `order` just gives the indices.  You then need to pass those indices to the data frame, to pick out the rows *at* those indices.

Also, as mentioned in the comments, you can use `head` instead of `tail` with `decreasing = TRUE` if you'd like, but that's a matter of taste.

Comment: No worries--if this answered your question, you can mark it as the answer.  :-)